# SVN caret sign [^]

Tags: svn, special-characters

I  have recently read a blog on SVN access to repository via different schema and came across `^` sign when we want to access our repository. The `^` sign I have understood is used when we want to go to the root's directory instead of typing the whole URL. I am trying to see the log messages using this `^` sign but got some issue. I am currently in my working copy.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caret sign has a special meaning in Windows CLI (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting)) so you should escape it. I think the following should work (I don't have Windows - I can't test it):

```
svn log ^^/branches
```